# How can I deploy a set of amplify files created by someone else to my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

How can I deploy a set of amplify files created by someone else to my AWS account?

I have an amplify project created by a complete stranger.
There is no hosting involved. Only the backend authentication and functions exist.
When I git clone the amplify project and try to do an amplify init or amplify push, the authentication and function categories are not recognized.
I checked the files and there is definitely a set of auth and function files in the backend folder.

When I do amplify add function, the function I created shows up in amplify push.
How do I deploy the existing auth and functions to amplify in my AWS account?
Rebuilding every resource with amplify add would be ridiculous.

Since the actual source code resides at a confidential URL other than github
You cannot specify the URL with amplify init --app.

How can I deploy a folder that exists on my local PC directly to my AWS account?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your AWS credentials are correctly configured for your project. You can update them using the AWS CLI or by checking your AWS configuration files.

Here's a step-by-step guide:

## Navigate to your project directory

cd /path/to/your/project

## Delete the Amplify folder

rm -rf amplify

After deleting the Amplify folder, restart your project and run the necessary Amplify commands to set up your project again.

#configure your amplify project
amplify configure

Enter the access key of the newly created user:
? accessKeyId:  # YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
? secretAccessKey:  # YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

## Initialize Amplify

amplify init

hope it will help you

Comment: How do I deploy an AMPLIFY project created by someone else to my AWS account,
Is it true that I have to delete the auth and functions once and recreate everything manually?
I find this very hard to believe.

Comment: for that you need credential of aws credential  profile  otherwise it not going to working (you can't push code into amplify from cli)

Comment: I have my own AWS account and full authorization. I have experience creating a completely new amplify project. I recognize that there was a problem with the way the question was written, so I will re-create the question. Thanks for replying.